# Примеры алгоритмов с логарифмической сложностью (основание отличное от 2)

Tags: сложность

Допустим, говорят, что алгоритм имеет сложность `O(log(N))`. Всегда ли эта запись означает, что логарифм берется по основанию `2`? Понимаю, что обычно людей интересует поведение функции, а не конкретные числа, но все же интересно, есть ли конкретные распространенные алгоритмы, которые оцениваются логарифмом с другим основанием?

Answer (score 5):

Ну это просто. Асимптотическая оценка сложности алгоритма O(N) не принимает во внимание константу перед множителем, тк при больших N она становится несущественной, следовательно O(N) = C1 * log(N) + C2 записывается как O(N) = log(N)

Известно также, что логарифм с любым основанием можно представить как логарифм по основанию 2 умноженный на множетель-константу, который по описанной выше причине просто не учитывается в оценке сложности O(N)

Comment: Кстати, если Вы хотите узнать больше и подробнее, настоятельно рекомендую книгу Кормена - Алгоритмы: построение и анализ (Introduction to Algorithms)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, книга Кормена все же больше для математиков, там, насколько я помню, слишком много теоретических задач. Себе пока присмотрел "Роберт Лафоре - Структуры данных и алгоритмы в Java".

Comment: не за что) Конечно на вкус и цвет, я в свое время читал с удовольствием!

Answer (score 3):

При учете асимптотической сложности константы не учитываются. Основание логарифма в данном случае не имеет значение. Т.к. логарифм можно привести к любому основанию, пользуясь свойством  [image: введите сюда описание изображения] .

Соответственно, если у нас есть обозначение O(логарифм n по основанию a), где a - это какая то константа, это выражение упрощается до O(логарифм n по основанию с разделить на логарифм a по основанию c), где c - это какая то константа. Получаем, что логарифм, на который делят, можно не учитывать в нотации O, т.к. он от n не зависит, и является константой.